# LottieFiles export is blurry, but looks fine in After Effects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, lottie, after-effects

my co-worker made a bunch of cool animations in AE. He's using illustrator for the assets. Everything looks great in AE, but once exported to LottieFiles, it's all blurry.

The hunch is this: the artboards in Illustrator are small, like 200x200 or so for most of them.

The canvas in After Effect is 1200x800. For every row, he has "continuous raster" checked. Everything looks good in AE!

After exporting to LottieFiles, it's all blurry, especially text (of course).

Simply sizing up the source asset in AI doesn't work because all the assets in AE have transforms applied to them.

Do we need to go back and resize all the assets in Illustrator, and then adjust all the transforms in AE? Or is there something we are overlooking? We looked thorugh the LottieFiles AE plugin for ways to scale exports and things like that but nothing really seemed to be appropriate.

Thanks!